# Unable to find library in eclipse for Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have the `zbar.jar` in my `libs` folder and I have linked it by Build Path/Configure Build Path

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load iconv from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/net.xxxxx.xxxx-2.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/net.xxxxx.xxxxxx-2]: findLibrary returned null
```

What else can i do to load this library?

[help http://assemblyx.net/Untitled-2.png](http://assemblyx.net/Untitled-2.png)
[help http://assemblyx.net/Untitled-1.png](http://assemblyx.net/Untitled-1.png)

Comment: Start by undoing your change to your build path. Just put the JAR in `libs/`. The Android tools will automatically add it to the compile path and the APK for use at runtime.

Comment: The name of your project is HRCDC, did you tried to hide it?

Comment: umm, i guess so, but @CommonsWare that didnt work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `zbar.jar`, the project requires you to have `iconv`. Check and make sure you copied over `libiconv.so`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are three workarounds that have worked for me:

1. Undo the change to your build path. Restart Eclipse/Android Studio and, finally, add the JAR file to your libs folder, Android Developer Tools will add it automatically to the build path.
2. Add the JAR file to your libs folder, if ADT doesn't add it to the build path, right click your project and select `Refresh`.
3. Undo the change, `Clean` your project and repeat step 1.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on *.jar file in the libs folder and then go to 'Build Path' --> 'Add to Build Path' - do clean and run.